# Como verificar se tag HTML tem determinado atributo com JS?

Tags: javascript, html5

Neste código:

```
<img id="SizeImage1" style="cursor:pointer">
```

Como você pode ver, não tem atributo `src`. Como posso saber se determinada tag tem um `src` ou não usando JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode verificar utilizando o método *hasAttribute()*, veja abaixo:

```
document.getElementById('SizeImage1').hasAttribute('src');
```

Vai te retornar *true* ou *false*.

Mais informações aqui: [W3Schools - hasAttribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_hasattribute.asp).

Comment: Consegui resolver problema usando hasAttribute(), https://jsfiddle.net/rsf6mn9n/

Comment: @MatheusMiranda então se a resposta do Douglas lhe resolveu o problema marque-a como correta por favor. Não somos um fórum, somos um Q&A, por favor faça o tour: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour para entender como o site funciona

Comment: Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento, eu vi documento como funciona o site.

Answer (score 3):

Outra forma é obtendo o valor de `src`, então verificar se está vazio ou não:

```js
var src1 = document.getElementById("SizeImage1").src
  , src2 = document.getElementById("SizeImage2").src;

// verifica se está null, '', undefined, 0
if (!src1)
 console.log("Primeiro está vazio");

if (!src2)
console.log("Segundo está vazio");
```

```html
<img id="SizeImage1" style="cursor:pointer">
<img id="SizeImage2" style="cursor:pointer" src="google.com">
```

Comment: Oi Lucas Costa, esse também funciona, obrigado pela resposta.